# How to shift the Google Maps zoom button to top

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, material-ui

I want to shift the position of my zoom panel slightly to the top in the image shared. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<GoogleMapReact
  bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}` }}
  defaultCenter={{
    lat: 42.361145,
    lng: -71.057083,
  }}
  defaultZoom={14}
  options={{ zoomControlOptions: { position: 0 } }}
  layerTypes={isTraffic ? ["TrafficLayer"] : []}
  yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
  onGoogleApiLoaded={handleApiLoaded}
> 
</GoogleMapReact>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change  the zoomControl position 
this way

```
        mapProperties.zoomControl = true;
        mapProperties.zoomControlOptions = {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        } ;
```

you can use `LEFT_TOP` or `RIGHT_TOP` for your need

```
  yourMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(you_map_id), mapProperties);
```

or based on your_sample

```
options={(maps) => ({
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
   position: maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  }
 })}
```

Comment: I have added the code. Can you advise me how to add specifically the Left position. Thank you.

Comment: This acts similar to options={{ zoomControlOptions: { position: 7 } }} and moves the zoom in/out panel to the TOP RIGHT of the page, where as I want it to shift a little on the top of my Add Icon so that it is visible and not overlapped by the Icon. Thank you.

Comment: the position for google maps control are manage by google maps style  .. using google maps feature you can only choose the place where you want see ...  the control ..  if you find the way for manage the css  use by google maps  .. let me know  .. (is better if you find a new position for your icon)